# add domain for the github pages, but not effect the project page

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

for example:

if I set the CNAME:
`exampledoamin.github.io` -> `blog.mydomain.com`

my projectpage will point to 
`exampledoamin.github.io/myprojectpage`
-> `blog.mydomain.com/myprojectpage`

---

now I want to  my projectpage use the default domain which the github given,

`exampledoamin.github.io/myprojectpage`.

Comment: Just remove your `CNAME` file from the repository

Comment: @PierrePrinetti but remove CNAME file that my blog address `blog.mydomain.com` would be not action

Comment: I guess that this repo is your first repo and GH makes it as default for you if you add CNAME file in it.. ilke `foo.github.io`, but you can try to create another repo, add the cname there, point that to your domain, and first repo would be like you need it to be :)